# string pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *s[] = { "knowledge","is","power"};
    char **p;
    p = s;
    printf("%s ", ++*p);
    printf("%s ", *p++);
    printf("%s ", ++*p);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> nowledge nowledge s

Please explain the output specially output from the 2nd `printf()` statement.I think that because `++` and `*` have same precedence therefore in `*p++` `p` should be incremented first and then use `*`(associativity from right to left for unary operators).

Comment: For reference:  in case it wasn't obvious, **this code alters `s[0]` and `s[1]`.**  If this array were being passed to you, that'd be a nasty side effect; you'd have made those pointers basically un`free`able.  This is part of why i hate combining dereferencing and increments -- it's quite easy to do the wrong thing.  :P

Comment: this is really homework? they don't have better things for you to learn? Or is this meant as a bad example, such that you learn *not* to do things like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

1. "*" has the same precedence as *prefix* "++" but must be avaluated **rigth to left**.

   printf("%s ", ++*p);

So first `*p` is evaluated, then `++(*p)`, leading to the second character in the first string.

1. "*" has **less** precedence than *suffix* "++".

   printf("%s ", *p++);

So first `p` is incremented, **but** it is a *post-increment*. The value returned from the operation *is the original one*. This way, the `*` operates over the original pointer, that pointed to the second char on the first string.

Note that, this time, `++` is operating over `p`, and not over `*p`.

1. Since "2", `p` points to the second string. When you do `++*p` you are now pointing to the second character of the second string ("s"). As you are again using a *pre-increment*, the value passed to `printf` is already changed.

   printf("%s ", ++*p);

I may get clearer if you do a little change and print the pointer value aswell (ignore the warnings):

```
printf("%s [%p]\n", ++*p, p );
printf("%s [%p]\n ", *p++, p );
printf("%s [%p]\n ", ++*p, p );

nowledge [0x7fff6f5519e0]
nowledge [0x7fff6f5519e8]
 s [0x7fff6f5519e8]
```

Comment: Nice answer, but aren't those prints UB since you're not guaranteed in what order the function arguments are evaluated?

Comment: @JoeFish - Yes, you are right. Those expressions have side effects, and that's why I said to ignore the compiler warnings. In a production code we must not rely in such expressions. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 5):

first one increments *p and displays the string (setting it to the n in knowldege).  second one displays the string *p then increments p (moving it to "is"). third one increments *p then displays the string (which starts at the s in "is").

Answer (score 2):

The value that the increment postfix operator (`p++`) evaluates to is `p`. The value that the increment prefix operator (`++p`) evaluates to is `p+1`.

In your second printf, `*p++` evaluates to what `*p` would evaluate to, but has the side effect of incrementing `p`.

Answer (score 1):

When faced with tricky sequences of operators, it's often easy to rewrite it as a series of simple statements. Your block becomes:

```
p[0]++;  //skips over the 'k' in knowledge
printf("%s", *p);
printf("%s", *p);
p++;     //moves to the next word
p[0]++;  //skips over the 'i' in is
printf("%s", *p);
```